# Problem with displaying Tkinter Frames inside another frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am having troubles with tkinter frames. I was hoping to have a window with a main frame. In that main frame I have a title label, top frame, and a bottom frame. I was hoping to use grid to place the title label and the top and bottom frame one after each other. The issue I came across was the title label and the bottom frame was not displaying.

heres my code:

```
    from tkinter import *

def addLabels(frame):
    lbl_date = Label(frame, text="DATE(DD/MM/YYYY)").grid(row=0,column=0)
    lbl_po = Label(frame, text="PO #").grid(row=0,column=1)
    lbl_nikls = Label(frame, text="NIKLS").grid(row=0,column=2)
    lbl_sro = Label(frame, text="SRO").grid(row=0,column=3)
    lbl_hours = Label(frame, text="HOURS").grid(row=0,column=4)
    lbl_otHours = Label(frame, text="OT HOURS").grid(row=0,column=5)
    lbl_dot = Label(frame, text="D-OT HOURS").grid(row=0,column=6)
    lbl_invoice = Label(frame, text="INVOICE #").grid(row=0,column=7)

def addEntry(frame):
    entry_date = Entry(frame).grid(row=1,column=0)
    entry_po = Entry(frame).grid(row=1,column=1)
    chk_nikls = Checkbutton(frame, text="").grid(row=1, column=2)
    chk_sro = Checkbutton(frame, text="").grid(row=1, column=3)
    entry_hours = Entry(frame).grid(row=1,column=4)
    entry_otHours = Entry(frame).grid(row=1,column=5)
    entry_dot = Entry(frame).grid(row=1,column=6)
    entry_invoice = Entry(frame).grid(row=1,column=7)    

##create window
window = Tk()

#main fraime
mainframe = Frame(master=window, borderwidth=1, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
##create and pack trinity header
lbl_title = Label(master=mainframe, text="Trinity Menu").grid(row=0)

##create frame for top view
top = Frame(master=mainframe, borderwidth=1, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1).grid(row=1)
addLabels(top)
addEntry(top)

##create frame for bottom view
bottom = Frame(master=mainframe, borderwidth=1, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1).grid(row=2)  
addLabels(bottom)

## run program
window.mainloop()
```

If you could please help that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is: you never use `place`, `pack` or `grid` on `mainframe`. Use something like:

```
mainframe = Frame(master=window, borderwidth=1, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
mainframe.pack()
```

The second one: you create a frame by using `e=Entry(...)`. Then `e` is an object of class `Entry`. You place it py using `a=e.grid(...)` etc. But then `a` is of type None. So `a=e.grid(...)` returns the same `a` (`NoneType`) as `a=Entry(...).grid(...)`, but you are not interested in that but in `e`. This is nor jQuery. So use:

```
lbl_title = Label(master=mainframe, text="Trinity Menu")
lbl_title.grid(row=0)
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: thanks for your help. I also forgot to pack the main frame so there was my other issue xD!